# T-sql Reset Row number on Field Change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, reset, row-number

Similar to a recent post of mine "t-sql sequential duration"”, but not exactly the same, I want to reset the row number based on a change in column x (in my case, column "who").

Here's the first query that returns the a small sample of the raw(ish) data:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT chr.custno, 
            CAST(LEFT(CONVERT( VARCHAR(20),chr.moddate,112),10)+ ' ' + chr.modtime AS DATETIME)as  moddate, 
            chr.who     
FROM        <TABLE> chr 
WHERE       chr.custno = 581827
            AND LEFT(chr.who, 5) = 'EMSZC'
            AND chr.[description] NOT LIKE 'Recalled and viewed this customer'
ORDER BY    chr.custno
```

Result:

```
custno      moddate             who
581827      2012-11-08 08:38:00.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:41:10.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:53:46.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:57:04.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:58:35.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:59:13.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 09:00:06.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 09:04:39.000     EMSZC49 Reset row number to 1
581827      2012-11-08 09:05:04.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:06:32.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:12:03.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:12:38.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:14:18.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:17:35.000     EMSZC14 Reset row number to 1
```

Second step is to add the row number (I didn’t do this in the first query because of the use of the word DISTINCT); so…

```
WITH c1 AS (
        SELECT      DISTINCT chr.custno
                    CAST(LEFT(CONVERT( VARCHAR(20),chr.moddate,112),10)+ ' ' + chr.modtime AS DATETIME)as moddate,
                    chr.who
        FROM        <TABLE> chr 
        WHERE       chr.custno = 581827
                    AND LEFT(chr.who, 5) = 'EMSZC'
                    AND chr.[description] NOT LIKE 'Recalled and viewed this customer'
        )

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY custno, moddate, who) AS RowID, custno, moddate, who
FROM    c1
```

Result:

```
RowID   custno      moddate                      who
1       581827      2012-11-08 08:38:00.000     EMSZC14
2       581827      2012-11-08 08:41:10.000     EMSZC14
3       581827      2012-11-08 08:53:46.000     EMSZC14
4       581827      2012-11-08 08:57:04.000     EMSZC14
5       581827      2012-11-08 08:58:35.000     EMSZC14
6       581827      2012-11-08 08:59:13.000     EMSZC14
7       581827      2012-11-08 09:00:06.000     EMSZC14
8       581827      2012-11-08 09:04:39.000     EMSZC49 Reset row number to 1
9       581827      2012-11-08 09:05:04.000     EMSZC49
10      581827      2012-11-08 09:06:32.000     EMSZC49
11      581827      2012-11-08 09:12:03.000     EMSZC49
12      581827      2012-11-08 09:12:38.000     EMSZC49
13      581827      2012-11-08 09:14:18.000     EMSZC49
14      581827      2012-11-08 09:17:35.000     EMSZC14 Reset row number to 1
```

The next step is where I’m stuck: the goal is to reset the RowID to 1 on each change of value in the “who” column.  The following code gets an “almost there” result (and it should be noted that I stole/borrowed this code from somewhere, but now I can’t find the website):

```
WITH c1 AS (
        SELECT      DISTINCT chr.custno,
                    CAST(LEFT(CONVERT( VARCHAR(20),chr.moddate,112),10)+ ' ' + chr.modtime AS DATETIME)as moddate,
                    chr.who
        FROM        <TABLE> chr 
        WHERE       chr.custno = 581827
                    AND LEFT(chr.who, 5) = 'EMSZC'
                    AND chr.[description] NOT LIKE 'Recalled and viewed this customer'
        )
, c1a AS    (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY custno, moddate, who) AS RowID, custno, moddate, who
            FROM    c1
            )

SELECT  x.RowID - y.MinID + 1 AS Row,
        x.custno, x.Touch, x.moddate, x.who      
FROM    (
            SELECT  custno, who, MIN(RowID) AS MinID
            FROM    c1a
            GROUP BY custno, who
        ) AS y
        INNER JOIN c1a x ON x.custno = y.custno AND x.who = y.who
```

Result:

```
Row custno      moddate                    who
1   581827      2012-11-08 08:38:00.000     EMSZC14
2   581827      2012-11-08 08:41:10.000     EMSZC14
3   581827      2012-11-08 08:53:46.000     EMSZC14
4   581827      2012-11-08 08:57:04.000     EMSZC14
5   581827      2012-11-08 08:58:35.000     EMSZC14
6   581827      2012-11-08 08:59:13.000     EMSZC14
7   581827      2012-11-08 09:00:06.000     EMSZC14
1   581827      2012-11-08 09:04:39.000     EMSZC49 Reset row number to 1 (Hooray! It worked!)
2   581827      2012-11-08 09:05:04.000     EMSZC49
3   581827      2012-11-08 09:06:32.000     EMSZC49
4   581827      2012-11-08 09:12:03.000     EMSZC49
5   581827      2012-11-08 09:12:38.000     EMSZC49
6   581827      2012-11-08 09:14:18.000     EMSZC49
14  581827      2012-11-08 09:17:35.000     EMSZC14 Reset row number to 1 (Crappies.)
```

DESIRED result:

```
Row custno      moddate                     who
1   581827      2012-11-08 08:38:00.000     EMSZC14
2   581827      2012-11-08 08:41:10.000     EMSZC14
3   581827      2012-11-08 08:53:46.000     EMSZC14
4   581827      2012-11-08 08:57:04.000     EMSZC14
5   581827      2012-11-08 08:58:35.000     EMSZC14
6   581827      2012-11-08 08:59:13.000     EMSZC14
7   581827      2012-11-08 09:00:06.000     EMSZC14
1   581827      2012-11-08 09:04:39.000     EMSZC49 Reset row number to 1 
2   581827      2012-11-08 09:05:04.000     EMSZC49
3   581827      2012-11-08 09:06:32.000     EMSZC49
4   581827      2012-11-08 09:12:03.000     EMSZC49
5   581827      2012-11-08 09:12:38.000     EMSZC49
6   581827      2012-11-08 09:14:18.000     EMSZC49
1   581827      2012-11-08 09:17:35.000     EMSZC14 Reset row number to 1
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 30):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 you can use [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to compare value with previous row and you can use [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) and [OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to record the changes.

```
with C1 as
(
  select custno,
         moddate,
         who,
         lag(who) over(order by moddate) as lag_who
  from chr
),
C2 as
(
  select custno,
         moddate,
         who,
         sum(case when who = lag_who then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(order by moddate rows unbounded preceding) as change 
  from C1
)
select row_number() over(partition by change order by moddate) as RowID,
       custno,
       moddate,
       who
from C2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/501c0/2/0)

**Update:**

A version for SQL Server 2005. It uses a recursive CTE and a temp table for intermediary storage of the data you need to iterate over.

```
create table #tmp
(
  id int primary key,
  custno int not null,
  moddate datetime not null,
  who varchar(10) not null
);

insert into #tmp(id, custno, moddate, who)
select row_number() over(order by moddate),
       custno,
       moddate,
       who
from chr;

with C as
(
  select 1 as rowid,
         T.id,
         T.custno,
         T.moddate,
         T.who,
         cast(null as varchar(10)) as lag_who
  from #tmp as T
  where T.id = 1
  union all
  select case when T.who = C.who then C.rowid + 1 else 1 end,
         T.id,
         T.custno,
         T.moddate,
         T.who,
         C.who
  from #tmp as T
    inner join C
      on T.id = C.id + 1
)
select rowid,
       custno,
       moddate,
       who
from C
option (maxrecursion 0);

drop table #tmp;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a649e/1/1)

Comment: Unfortunately, we are still running 2005 with plans to upgrade to 2008R2 next month.  The LAG function would be a clean solution to this problem.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention...just another argument for moving to SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Very cool solution.  My only concern (and it's not founded in fact) is the use of 0 with maxrecursion.  That could cause an infinite loop, but in thinking about my data structure, probably not with the data I've got.  Thank you!!!

Comment: This LAG function is exactly what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I had success with this issue by using Rank():

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY who ORDER BY custno, moddate) AS RANK
```

This returned your desired results.  I actually found this post trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY custno, moddate, who)
```

try:

```
PARTITION BY custno, who ORDER BY custno, moddate)
```

Comment: Tried that already (it seems like it should work, doesn't it?) but it still returns the same result set with the last row number = 14.  Keep throwing ideas at me, though.  I'm just missing some simple step, I'm sure.

Answer (score -2):

The only solution I can think of is to use a cursor (ugh) and suffer through the RBAR process.  NOT an elegant solution as the cursor will have to read in excess of 1m rows.  Bummer.