# Ranking: How to reset the ROW_NUMBER or RANK to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, ranking

Using SQL Server 2014:

Consider the following table:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
      Id int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
      Col_Value varchar(2)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Col_Value)
VALUES ('A'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('A'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('B'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('A'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('C'),('A'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('C')
```

How can I create a query that produces R column in the result like below

```
+----+------+---+
| ID | Data | R |
+----+------+---+
| 1  | A    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 2  | A    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 3  | B    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 4  | B    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 5  | B    | 3 |
+----+------+---+
| 6  | A    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 7  | A    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 8  | B    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 9  | B    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 10 | B    | 3 |
+----+------+---+
| 11 | A    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 12 | B    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 13 | B    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 14 | A    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 15 | A    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 16 | B    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 17 | C    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 18 | C    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 19 | A    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 20 | A    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 21 | B    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
| 22 | B    | 2 |
+----+------+---+
| 23 | C    | 1 |
+----+------+---+
```

In the above result table, once Data column changes in a row, the R value resets to 1

**Update 1**

Ben Thul's answer works very well.

I suggest below post be updated with a reference to this answer.

[T-sql Reset Row number on Field Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405264/t-sql-reset-row-number-on-field-change)

Comment: Row_number() over (partition by data order by id)

Comment: @dman2306, not the result from your query is far from the output listed in the post.

Comment: @artm, the post you are referring does not have a confirmed answer. Also, the answer seems to be limited to much earlier version of SQL Server. I expect SQL 14 provides a clean solution here.

Comment: @artm, the other post should be referred to this answer. works very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as a "gaps and islands" problem in the literature. First, my proposed solution:

```
with cte as (
    select *, [Id] - row_number() over (partition by [Col_Value] order by [Id]) as [GroupID]
    from @table
)
select [Id], [Col_Value], row_number() over (partition by [GroupID], [Col_Value] order by [Id])
from cte
order by [Id];
```

For exposition, note that if I enumerate all of the "A" values using `row_number()`, those that are contiguous have the `row_number()` value go up at the same rate as the Id value. Which is to say that their difference will be the same for those in that contiguous group (also known as an "island"). Once we calculate that group identifier, it's merely a matter of enumerating each member per group.