# Reset Row Number on value change, but with repeat values in partition

Tags: sql-server, lag, row-number, ranking-functions, partition-by

I'm having trouble with something very similar to this question
[T-sql Reset Row number on Field Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405264/t-sql-reset-row-number-on-field-change)

The solution to this question is perfect, works fine. Except when I try with multiple other 'custno', it breaks down.

What I mean by that:

```
custno      moddate                     who
--------------------------------------------------
581827      2012-11-08 08:38:00.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:41:10.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:53:46.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:57:04.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:58:35.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 08:59:13.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 09:00:06.000     EMSZC14
581827      2012-11-08 09:04:39.000     EMSZC49 Reset row number to 1
581827      2012-11-08 09:05:04.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:06:32.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:12:03.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:12:38.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:14:18.000     EMSZC49
581827      2012-11-08 09:17:35.000     EMSZC14 Reset row number to 1
-- my new rows for example of problem
581829      2012-11-08 09:12:03.000     EMSZC14 1
581829      2012-11-08 09:12:38.000     EMSZC49 1
581829      2012-11-08 09:14:18.000     EMSZC49
581829      2012-11-08 09:17:35.000     EMSZC14 Reset row number to 1
```

The introduction of a new `custno` breaks this solution, which works perfectly for the one `custno`.

```
with C1 as
(
    select 
        custno, moddate, who,
        lag(who) over(order by moddate) as lag_who
    from 
        chr
),
C2 as
(
    select 
        custno, moddate, who,
        sum(case when who = lag_who then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(order by moddate rows unbounded preceding) as change 
    from 
        C1
)
select 
    row_number() over(partition by change order by moddate) as RowID,
    custno, moddate, who
from 
    C2
```

I'm sure it's only a little tweak to handle multiple custno's, but this is already way beyond my capabilities and I managed to make it work for my data but that was purely by replacing column and table names. Unfortunately don't have a detailed enough understanding to resolve the issue I have.

My data looks like

```
custno   start_date    value
```

effectively exactly the same. I want a Row/rank of 1 for every time the 'value' or 'who' changes, regardless if that value/who has been seen before. This is all relative to a `custno`. And I do see instances where a value/who can return back to the same value as well. Again, solution above handled that 'repetition' just fine... but for the one `custno`

I'm thinking I just need to somehow add some sort of grouping by `custno` in somewhere? Just not sure where or how

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and we can use the difference in row numbers method here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY moddate) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, who ORDER BY moddate) rn2
    FROM chr
)

SELECT custno, moddate, who,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY moddate) rn
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    custno,
    moddate;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

For an explanation of the difference in row number method used here, `rn1` is just a time-ordered sequence from 1 onwards, per customer, according to the data you have shown above.  The `rn2` sequence is partitioned additionally by `who`.  It is the case the *difference* between `rn1` and `rn2` will always have the same value, for each customer.  It is with this difference that we then take a row number over the entire table to generate the sequence you actually want to see.

Comment: Wow, that's it! And the code is even simpler than the solution for the other question! I'll do some more validation but i made a quick #temp of 3 custno, totalling about 90 rows with changes in value/who and even for the repeating values/who it correctly reset to 1 AND did that for ALL of the custno's! Thank you so much! And answered in minutes! Legendary, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does have a flaw: see following [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a056aa4bb38620b2145900f85f3aa66). If "who" column changes value in second row for one row, it will cause rn1-rn2 to realign and continue count from 2 instead of resetting to 1.

Answer (score 2):

The last ROW_NUMBER clause should be:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, who, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY custno, moddate) rn
```

Try changing the second and fourth records to EMSZC49 and you'll see what I mean. You'll get the same issue anytime the first *n* who records match the next *n* who records.