# Reset Row Number on value change, but repeat values in partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a problem with the answered question from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538370)

Can you find the solution?
It's wrong result `rn` Column if the data `chr` like this one

```
WITH chr AS (
    SELECT 581827 AS custno, '2012-11-08 08:38:00.000' AS moddate, 'EMSZC14' AS who UNION ALL
    SELECT 581827, '2012-11-08 09:14:18.000', 'EMSZC49' UNION ALL
    SELECT 581827, '2012-11-08 09:17:35.000', 'EMSZC14' UNION ALL  -- It is Fail
    SELECT 581827, '2012-11-08 09:17:35.000', 'EMSZC14'   -- It is Fail
),
cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY moddate) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, who ORDER BY moddate) rn2
    FROM chr
)

SELECT custno, moddate, who,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY moddate) rn
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    custno,
    moddate;
```

Wrong Result :

```
custno  moddate who rn
581827  2012-11-08 08:38:00.000 EMSZC14 1
581827  2012-11-08 09:14:18.000 EMSZC49 1
581827  2012-11-08 09:17:35.000 EMSZC14 2
581827  2012-11-08 09:17:35.000 EMSZC14 3
```

Expected Result :

```
custno  moddate who rn
581827  2012-11-08 08:38:00.000 EMSZC14 1
581827  2012-11-08 09:14:18.000 EMSZC49 1
581827  2012-11-08 09:17:35.000 EMSZC14 1
581827  2012-11-08 09:17:35.000 EMSZC14 2
```

Comment: Can you better describe what `It is Fail` is supposed actually mean here?  The query you included is correct for what its original intention was.

Comment: You need to make your question stand alone, i.e. provide sample data, expected results, and actual results so we can see what isn't working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wrong Result i meant , updated my question

Comment: @DaleK Sample data in that query. Updated my question for expected result and wrong result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `who` in the final `row_number` as follows:

```
WITH chr AS (
    SELECT 581827 AS custno, '2012-11-08 08:38:00.000' AS moddate, 'EMSZC14' AS who UNION ALL
    SELECT 581827, '2012-11-08 09:14:18.000', 'EMSZC49' UNION ALL
    SELECT 581827, '2012-11-08 09:17:35.000', 'EMSZC14' UNION ALL  -- It is Fail
    SELECT 581827, '2012-11-08 09:17:35.000', 'EMSZC14'   -- It is Fail
),
cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno ORDER BY moddate) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, who ORDER BY moddate) rn2
    FROM chr
)

SELECT custno, moddate, who,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custno, who, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY moddate) rn
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    custno,
    moddate;
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f9715ccb3978b8fd7e235b7774905f30)